# Clean way of creating dynamic queries from request parameters

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC 3.2 and I use JPA for my persistence layer. I would like to do the following:

When a request like this arrive `/some-item?param1=something&param2=123&order-by=some-field` I want to be able to automatically build a query in the persistence layer so that I don't have to create one billion methods for `getAllItemsWith(final String param1, final String param2...)` and so on.

I have thought of capturing the request parameters in a `Map` and then pass this to the repository layer where I have a predefined list of params that I will check if exists in the map, and if it does add the necassaray condition. However, I wonder if there are other better ways to do this?

Comment: A question like this just came up 4 questions down in `Java`. The way you propose is probably the easiest. However, you are possibly giving away the names of your columns in your urls.

Answer (score 1):

I've found an elegant way to solve this problem. There is such sql opeartor as "coalese" (some explanations: http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-coalesce.html). It allows to pass any parameters to query and be sure that `null` parameters will be ignored.

Example of my DAO interface (Spring data-jpa, MySQL):

```
@Query("select b from Book b where " +
                "coalesce(b.name, '') like concat('%', :name, '%') " +
                "and coalesce(b.author, '') like concat('%', :author, '%') " +
                "and coalesce(b.category, '') like concat('%', :category, '%') " +
                "and coalesce(b.publisher, '') like concat('%', :publisher, '%') " +
                "and (b.available = :available1 or b.available = :available2)")
    public Page<Book> findByParams(
                @Param("name") String name
                , @Param("author") String author
                , @Param("category") String category
                , @Param("publisher") String publisher
                , @Param("available1") Boolean available1, @Param("available2") Boolean available2
                , Pageable pageReq);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

it is difficult to do some with even criteria api.
you can take a look at lucene Solr indexing engine which is primarily used for advanced search purposes involving many search conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth looking at the [Spring Data - JPA project](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/jpa).  You will still have to create interfaces for all the combinations of params, but at least they will be automatically implemented.